# iPad like window animation in Swing

Tags: swing, ipad

Those floating, sliding and flying maze of pup ups and windows in iPad are very cool. I wonder if it's possible to achieve those effects with java swing applications. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is possible. You have to **use animation library such as [Trident](http://kenai.com/projects/trident/pages/Home) or [TimingFramework](https://timingframework.dev.java.net/)**.

I suggest to try Trident first simply because TimingFramework is stale for several years now.